# Generate multiple PDF files using single for loop in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, mpdf

I am using mpdf library in CodeIgniter for generating PDF files.

I want 4 files to be generated from single for loop. But it is only generating one file.

Below is the code

```
$dataArr = $notificationReports['data'];
        $chunkReport = count($dataArr);

        if($chunkReport > 1000){
            $chunkSize = ($chunkReport / 4);
            $chunks = array_chunk($dataArr,$chunkSize);
            for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++){

                $this->load->library('mpdf56/mpdf');
                $paper='A4';
                $notificationReports['data'] = $chunks[$i];
                $notificationReports['heading'] = array(
                                    'S. NO',
                                    'SENT DATE',
                                    'SENT BY',
                                    'SENT TO',
                                    'MESSAGE',
                                    'SMS'
                                );


                $mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8',$paper,'','','','','',10,'',3,'L');
                $html = $this->load->view('reports/pdf_view_report',$notificationReports,true);
                $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
                $mpdf->Output($title.".pdf",'D');
                unset($mpdf);
                unset($notificationReports);
                unset($html);
```

Even I have removed these unset methods, and not only this, I have printed this data by applying comments on the code. Data inside the loop is fine, but only not generating multiple files. It is only generating single file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, you shouldn't be loading library in a loop `$this->load->library('mpdf56/mpdf');`. Load it once for all your pdf operations.

Comment: I have tried that also. But nothing happened.

Comment: Okay, I have same problem when I want to email several PDF files as attachment from inside a loop. First one is fine, all other attachments or the same as the first file. Any progress on this issue??

Answer (score 1):

I was also working on similar thing,

I changed

```
$mpdf->Output($title.".pdf",'D');
```

TO

```
$mpdf->Output('c:/pdf/'.$title.".pdf",'F');
```

This create file in the location specified

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
$mpdf->Output($title.$i.".pdf",'D');
```

Instead of

```
$mpdf->Output($title.".pdf",'D');
```

Comment: yes I have also tried this as well. But only first file is downloading with name0.pdf